# SAQL: How to count yes/no responses to chatbot question

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I've been using Salesforce for less than two months and EA less than one.

Requirement: I need to create a report that answers the question, "What is the client feedback on the chatbot?"

Data: I have the conversation event log that details when the chatbot prompts the question "Did this resolve your issue?" and how the user responds to it. I have the data listed in a table below along with the ID for each chat session.

Problem: The user response isn't unique.  However, looking at the data I would expect a user response within 1s of the prompt.  I think this should be able to solve my problem?

Solution:  In the example below I would want this to track as a user response of 1.  How could I make sure that I'm only counting the user response within a certain time frame?

[image: Data Sample]